# Как сделать чтобы функция применялась к каждому элементу? (Убрать placeholder при фокусе на input)

Tags: javascript, html

Изучаю JS. Решил посидеть поэкспериментировать.

```js
const loginInput = document.querySelector(".login_input");
const placeholderAttr = loginInput.getAttribute("placeholder");

loginInput.addEventListener("focus", () => {
  if (placeholderAttr.length > 1) {
    loginInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "")
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Login" id="login_input" class="login_input">
  <div class="pwd_container">
    <input type="password" id="pwd_input login_input" class="pwd_input login_input" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="hide_pwd_icon"><img src="img/eye.svg" alt="" width="18"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Как сделать чтоб placeholder удалялся у кажого input'a. В данному случае удаляется только у первого инпута Login

Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: `onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"`

Answer (score 1):

Читайте код, чтобы его понимать.
Вы вешаете обработчик только на один элемент - `document.querySelector(".login_input")`

Чтобы повесить на несколько, нужно "повесить на несколько", например так

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('input'); // Возмём !все! элементы input, т.е. наша переменная является массивом с этими элементами.


elements.forEach(function(e){ // Проходим циклом по всем элементам
  e.addEventListener('focus', function(e){ // И на каждый вешаем один и тот же обработчик
    e.target.value = 'FOCUS';
  });
  
  e.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    e.target.value = '';
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
```

Или пользуемся делегирование событий, это лучший вариант (ИМХО).
Подробнее почитайте тут - [ссылка](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation)

```js
document.body.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
  //Обработчик вешается уже какой-то родитель, который содержит в себе все эти элементы.
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    e.target.value = 'FOCUS';
  }
}, true);

document.body.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    e.target.value = '';
  }
}, true);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
<input type="text" value="">
```

Comment: про blur я не догадался - + в карму

Answer (score 1):

> (Убрать placeholder при фокусе на input)

Подозреваю, что имелось в виду следующее поведение:

```css
input.login_input:focus::placeholder { color: #0000; }
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Login" id="login_input" class="login_input">
  <div class="pwd_container">
    <input type="password" id="pwd_input login_input" class="pwd_input login_input" placeholder="Password">
    <span class="hide_pwd_icon"><img src="img/eye.svg" alt="" width="18"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```